# Disable warning in Xcode Playgrounds

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, swift-playground, xcplayground

How do I disable the awful pop-under warning behavior in Playgrounds?

[image: NSAnnoying]

Trying to code when this happens is pointless, since the entire frame moves with it.

....NSAnnoying!